# Erro Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array

Tags: php

Não estou conseguindo fazer o `header location` redirecionar para um campo da tabela.

Nesse campo, tem o link de um documento PDF.

Vejam o código:

```
case 'mostra-id':  

$link = Connection::select("SELECT link FROM `arquivos` where id =" . App::$key);

$sql = "update `arquivos` set `acessos`= acessos + 1 where id=" . App::$key;
$dados = Connection::exec($sql);

header('Location: ' . $link['link']);
break;
```

O link na tabela está gravado dessa forma: `sistema/public/arquivos/pdf/01.pdf`

O update normalmente está correto, mas não abre o link quando redireciono. Dando o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in

Comment: Fiquei meio na dúvida, o link só não aparece pelo header location, mas quando você bota o link direto pelo navegador ele funciona, correto?

Comment: Faça `print_r($link);` e coloque o resultado aqui comnetários.

Comment: PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT link FROM `arquivos` where id =10 )

Comment: Não tens de executar o `$link` para obteres o resultado da BD?

Comment: Sim, funcionou dessa forma: header('Location: ' . $link->fetchColumn(0));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$link` não é um array para ser manuseado da maneira que você fez, é um objeto [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) então precisa manusear de jeito diferente.

Tente `$link->fetchColumn(0)`, [esta é a documentação dele](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php), esse comando irá buscar a primeira coluna da próxima linha do result set.

Comment: Funcionou certinho cara. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in

O erro sugere que o retorno do select não é um array mas provavelmente um objeto, então mude a notação de:

```
header('Location: ' . $link['link']);
```

Para:

```
header('Location: ' . $link->link);
```

Comment: Deu o mesmo erro.